# Make entire div clickable

Tags: clickable

I am trying to get the whole div clickable and this works but only with a straight link to another site. Is there a way to make it work with this text in it also:

```
<div class='reddit' title='Share Us On Reddit' onclick="window.open('http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=httpsFwww.example.com&amp;title=XXX is Cape Breton's Homepage. Start Your Web Search With Beautiful Cape Breton Island')">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[From CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/)

> This probably isn't a thing you need to rely on JavaScript for
>   anymore. Since HTML5, this is perfectly valid:
>
> ```
> <a href="http://example.com">
>   <div>
>      anything
>   </div>
> </a>
> ```
>
> And remember you can make links `display: block;` so sometimes you
>   don't even need the div.

Comment: How could I do the same thing with the code below. Thanks.....<button class="download-button" type="button" name="">
<span class="download-button-content"><a href=""><img src="https://www.example.com/images/pages/sethomepage/64-chrome.png"/>Install Our Google Chrome Extension</a></span>
</button>

Comment: Create a jsfiddle. I suggest you to use <a> instead of <button> for ease..

Answer (score 3):

```html
<div  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="document.location='evenidontknow-page.html'">
  <h2>Full Div Clickable</h2>
  </div
```

The above code helped me very well, and this will not require any extra code.

Using **a** tag may solve the problem but we need to add extra code to it.

please check this link for more info [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has a feature called "Stretched Link". From the documentation:

> Make any HTML element or Bootstrap component clickable by “stretching” a nested link via CSS.

You can read more by visiting the following link:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/stretched-link/